# Capturing kill code of go process?

Tags: unix, go, kill

I'm trying to write a test that would drive out functionality for kill commands. To do this, I need the target of my test (a very simple go http server - https://github.com/jadekler/git-grunt-gostop/blob/master/test/fixtures/gostop_basic.go) to differentiate between having been killing with -2 vs -9. Is there some way to do this? It seems as though go's defer doesn't happen regardless of -2 vs -9, which was my first try. Subsequent research has not been enlightening.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Did you start the process yourself, and want the signal that caused it to exit; or are you trying to handle the signals with the `signal` package?

Comment: Hey - thanks for the reply. Yes, I started the process myself, and for right now I'm just trying to run `kill -2 <pid>` to see some resultant outcome. edit: however, the intent for this is so that an external javascript process will start it, and a different one will stop it. AKA i cannot look at exit codes from the thing that spawned the process. :/

Comment: Well, you can't `wait` on non-child process, so there's no way to get the exit status directly. If you really need the exit status, you need to start it yourself, or have the actual parent process communicate it it some way.

Comment: Note that you can't trap SIGKILL (9): it causes the process to terminate with no opportunity to do any special handling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can catch signals using the [`os/signal` package](http://golang.org/pkg/os/signal/).  You can catch `SIGINT` with code something like this:

```
import (
    "os"
    "os/signal"
)
...

// the signal module will lose notifications if the channel is not ready to receive, so give it a buffer
ch := make(chan os.Signal, 5)
go func() {
    for sig := range ch {
        // interrupt signal received
        os.Exit(0)
    }
}()
signal.Notify(ch, os.SIGINT)
```

Unfortunately, you can't do the same for `SIGKILL`.  From the `signal(7)` man page:

> The signals `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.

Comment: Ah! This looks promising. Thank you!